# Access Div Id placed in _Layout MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in MVC3. I have created a DIV in _Layout.cshtml file  for showing Error Messages and i have created a C# class ErrorMessage in Views Folder.

DIV in _layout.cshtml file:

```
<div class="ErrorMessageBox" id="ErrorMessageDiv" runat="server"> </div>
```

This is class ErrorMessage code:

```
public static class ErrorMessage

{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        ErrorMessageDiv.InnerText = message;
    }
    public static void Hide()
    {
    }
}
```

In the class ErrorMessage it gives error "ErrorMessageDiv does not exist in current context"

Any idea how to do it in MVC3?

Comment: First things first, get rid of that runat from your div. I don't see reason to ever use this in mvc, then try Antony's solution below

Answer (score 0):

You should read about mvc pattern - how it work. In a few words:

-> request -> creating controller -> executing some Action methods -> Render View

There are no page life cycle events like page_load or page_prerender in asp.net mvc. All business logic you have to do in controller. Your view just render result.

In your case:
Check input values in controller action method set some flag in ViewBag like

```
public ActionResult HomeM(string inputParam)
{
    ViewBag.Error = String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputParam);
    return View();
}
```

your view:

```
@if (ViewBag.Error)
{
     <div class="ErrorMsg">Error text</div>
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but still facing some problem. It works only first time but after that the state of ErrorMsg Div remains same because i want to show it only when there is some errors and hide the Div otherwise.

Comment: it's normal case but i didn't understand where the problem is? If you make request to this action - code which set ViewBag.Error always execute, so the ViewBag.Error always could be true or false.

Comment: i would change `String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputParam);` to the actual error message and in the view do the IsNullOrEmpty check -> `@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Error))`{div class="ErrorMsg">ViewBag.Error</div>}